# Unity3d AddComponent taking variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-components

**Details:**
In C# on Unity3d
Searched on the unity documentation but the example doesn't fit to my case, same for other websites i visited. (i did not list them as i should.)

What i am trying to do is passing a class variable with a constructor to be a component:

```
CustomComponentClass ccc = new CustomComponentClass(2343, "blop");
gameObject.AddComponent(ccc);
```

I want to know if what i am trying shoud work, or if i missed something...

**Problem:**

```
gameObject.AddComponent(ccc); -> cannot convert ccc to string.

gameObject.AddComponent<ccc>(); -> Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? (i'm not, i'm using a variable and all is in the same namespace)

gameObject.AddComponent<CustomComponentClass>(ccc); -> UnityEngine.GameObject.AddComponent(string) cannot be used with the type arguments

gameObject.AddComponent<CustomComponentClass>(2343, "blop"); -> No overload for method AddComponent takes 2 arguments
```

Whatever i try doesn't work.
C# is not really like javascript, if i'm right we used to be able to pass variables in the addcomponent in js.

**Context:**
I must absolutely pass it in the constructor.
I have 2 fields that are private, and i can't affort it tobe static, constants, or public for safety reason.

**Options:**
If the answer is too complicated for me i will probably make get/set and check if the fields are empty.

Comment: You absolutely do not need to pass it in to the constructor. Instead create the component as normal (without parameters), add the component to the gameobject, then call a setup method on the component that provides the necessary parameters and runs whatever code you currently have in the constructor.

Comment: Thought about making get/sets but never thought about a method to do the setup xD
Thanks :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You absolutely do not need to pass it in to the constructor.

Instead create the component as normal (without parameters), add the component to the gameobject, then call a setup method on the component that provides the necessary parameters and runs whatever code you currently have in the constructor.

Comment: I know this is old. But I'm also having this problem and don't quite understand this solution. What do you mean by *"call a setup method on the component that provides the necessary parameters and runs whatever code you currently have in the constructor"*? Is the setup method in the component? If so, how will it know what parameters to provide? Sorry if it's a newb question, been stuck at this for some hours now haha.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. I first set the `gameObject.SetActive(false)` added the component `MyComponent myComponent = gameObject.AddComponent<MyComponent>()` then changed what I needed to change `myComponent.SetMyVar("example")` then set the game object to active `gameObject.SetActive(true)`. Adding this in case anyone ran into the same confusion I ran into.